# How to set a maximum/upper bound for method calls in RhinoMocks with the Times() method?

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I'm trying to test that a method is called between 3 and 4 times:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Rhino.Mocks;
using StructureMap.AutoMocking;

namespace AutoMockPlayground
{
    [TestClass]
    public class SomeTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Bara_ShouldBeCalledThreeOrFourTimes()
        {
            var autoMocker = new RhinoAutoMocker<Foo>(MockMode.AAA);

            var barMock = autoMocker.Get<IBar>();

            // Bara() should not be called more than four times
            barMock.Stub(bar => bar.Bara()).Repeat.Times(3, 4);

            autoMocker.ClassUnderTest.DoSomeThing();

            barMock.VerifyAllExpectations();
        }
    }

    public interface IBar
    {
        void Bara();
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        private readonly IBar _bar;

        public Foo(IBar bar)
        {
            _bar = bar;
        }

        public void DoSomeThing()
        {
            _bar.Bara();
            _bar.Bara();
            _bar.Bara();
            _bar.Bara();
            _bar.Bara();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the `Repeat.Times(int min, int max)`, but the `max` argument does not seem to have any effect.
This test passes although `Bara()` is called 5 times.

How can I express in my test that `Bara()` should be called between 3 and 4 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stub by definition will not check the expectation, see also [this](http://www.wrightfully.com/on-rhino-mocks-verifyallexpectations-vs-assertwascalled/).
However, you can verify the expectation simply by calling `AssertWasCalled`
You can modify your code as follows:

```
    var autoMocker = new RhinoAutoMocker<Foo>(MockMode.AAA);

    var barMock = autoMocker.Get<IBar>();

    autoMocker.ClassUnderTest.DoSomeThing();

    // Bara() should not be called more than four times
    barMock.AssertWasCalled(bar => bar.Bara(),     
                            options => options.IgnoreArguments().Repeat.Times(3,4));
```

Comment: The test fails, if ``Bara()`` is called only twice, therefore, your statement about stubs not checking expectations is not true. (Maybe that's due to using a ``RhinoAutoMocker`` which probably calls ``GenereteMock()``)

Comment: The ``AssertWasCalled()`` syntax works as I expected it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `RhinoAutoMocker`, but it looks like `barMock` is being used as a stub object rather than a mock object.

If it's a stub (i.e. by using .Stub()) then calling `VerifyAllExpectations()` will have not effect. Instead, it needs to be a mock object, where calling `VerifyAllExpectations()` should work.

For example, here's how I use a mock in my tests.

```
var mockObject = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFoo>();

mockObject.Expect(o => o.CallSomething().Repeat.Times(1);

mockObject.VerifyAllExpecttions();
```

So instead of

`barMock.Stub(bar => bar.Bara()).Repeat.Times(3, 4);`

can you do

`barMock.Expect(bar => bar.Bara()).Repeat.Times(3, 4);`

EDIT:

Just to expand:

**Stub**

A stub is an object which you do not intend to assert anything against. You use a stub to plug in default values for method return values, or to stub out calls to `void` methods.

Calling `.Verfiyxxxx` on a stub object will have no effect, since by definition a stub does not keep track of how that object was interacted with, it simply knows "When method x() is called, do this other action instead".

**Mock**

If you wish to assert an interaction with an object e.g. that a method was called 4 times, or a method was called with a particular set of arguments, then you need a mock object. Using a mock entails calling `Expect` (this depends on the mocking framework you're using, but it's usually `Expect`)

Comment: Probably, I should use ``Expect()`` instead of ``Stub()``, but even when using ``Stub()`` the test fails, if ``Bara()`` is only called twice.

And it does not work with ``Expect()``, either, the test still passes.